# Angular no compila bien la aplicacion

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy ejecutando ng build y me ejecuta todo correctamente. Pero al ingresar a la pagina desde la carpeta de produccion para probarlo, sale la pagina en blanco y no funciona. Revise la consola y me sale estos errores

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> runtime.7b63b9fd40098a2e8207.js:1 Failed to load resource:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND polyfills.94daefd414b8355106ab.js:1 Failed to

> load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND main.ce781be5ae1c5242ef7e.js:1

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND bg-textura.png:1

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

> /C:/assets/img/logo.png:1 Failed to load resource:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

No entiendo porque me compila mal, y cuando lo testeo no me salta ningun error.

Orden de carpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La carpeta de producción es la raíz del servidor o es un subdirectorio?

Comment: Es un subdirectorio generado llamado dist y dentro de dist esta angular-test y dentro de angular test el root de produccion

Comment: Ok. Según lo que entiendo estás abriendo directamente el index.html desde el explorador de archivos. Para que funcione tienes que copiar los archivos de producción a un servidor web y servir la página desde ahí.

Comment: Haa entiendo, debe ser eso entonces